# UICollectionView cell's content's height (based on attributed string)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I've got a `UICollectionView` which holds 4 different types of cells, one of which is supposed to contain a `UIView` with a `UITextView` inside. The `UITextView` will have different attributed strings of dynamic height set in it so the entire cell also needs to resize its height accordingly - I can't have any scrolling in it.

I get the height of the attributed string through its size property. I specify the cell height as that amount in the method.

```
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout
  sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}
```

That's working quite fine - I can see that the cell is longer.

Now, for some reason I can't make its subviews longer - setting a new frame simply doesn't have any effect:

```
CGRect frameCellOriginal = self.textTest.frame;
CGRect frameCellNew = CGRectMake(frameCellOriginal.origin.x, frameCellOriginal.origin.y, frameCellOriginal.size.width, frameCellOriginal.size.height / 2 + atString.size.height);
self.textTest.frame = frameCellNew;
```

I tried using the `setNeedsDisplay` method on the `UITextView` but that didn't change anything. I also tried using `setAutoresizesSubviews:YES` and `setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` on both the cell and its subviews but it didn't work either.

Anyone got any ideas?

**Edit:**

I just noticed that the 1st time I scroll through the collection, the view containing the text is as small as in the .xib file. Then, if I scroll it again, its white background `UIView` becomes longer and fills the entire cell - taking the height I set it to. On the 3rd scroll the `UITextView` also takes said height.

I've no idea why that happens if I set all 3 views in the same method...

Comment: Try setting the cell's contentView frame.

Comment: @jeffamaphone I tried that just now but it didn't change anything :(
Also, please see my edit.

Comment: You should reset the sizes in prepareForReuse.  Use view.layer.borderColor and view.layer.borderWidth to show the outlines to make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: For now I had to add all the Views manually to a ScrollView as there was no time to spend on it anymore; I'll try to follow this idea and get back to you with any updates. Thanks for your help :)